# "405 Method Not Allowed" for Artifactory API call

Tags: artifactory

I'm trying to find all projects created between the times `1493872000` and `1493872435` on Artifactory, but I'm getting 405.

```
$ curl -X POST -H "X-JFrog-Art-Api: <KEY>" "http://localhost:8081/artifactory/api/search/creation?from=1493872000&to=1493872435&repos=project1"

{
  "errors" : [ {
    "status" : 405,
    "message" : "Method Not Allowed"
  } ]
}
```

Is there something wrong with my command? I'm using the documentation [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-ArtifactsCreatedinDateRange).

Not all the API calls seem to work for me, but `curl -H "X-JFrog-Art-Api: <KEY>" -X PUT "http://localhost:8081/artifactory/project1/artifacts.zip" -T artifacts.zip` (to upload an artifact) does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use GET, not POST:

```
curl -X GET -H "X-JFrog-Art-Api: <KEY>" "http://localhost:8081/artifactory/api/search/creation?from=1493872000&to=1493872435&repos=project1"
```